# Updating existing String elements of an ArrayBuffer in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an `ArrayBuffer` of `Strings` as below:

```
var myList = ArrayBuffer[String]()
myList += "abc"
myList += "def"
```

Now, I'm trying to update the `String` in the `ArrayBuffer` based on some condition:

```
for(item <- myList){
  if(some condition){
    item = "updatedstring"
  }
}
```

When I try to do this, I get an error saying `val` cannot be reassigned. Why do I get this error even though I have declared `myList` as a `var`? If I cannot update it this way, how else can I update the elements when iterating through the `ArrayBuffer`? I'm new to Scala, so I apologize if I got this all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would point out is that `item` is not the same as `myList` - it's an element within `myList`, and the way that Scala iteration works, it's a `val`.  There are various reasons for this related to immutability which I won't get into here.

I would recommend this instead:

```
val myNewList = myList.map(originalString =>
    if (someCondition) "xyz"
    else originalString
)
```

Then, if you feel so inclined, you could do `myList = myNewList` (or just forgo having a `myNewList` entirely and do `myList = myList.map(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop `item` is a local `val`. Therefore, it cannot be changed. 
You could:

either iterate through the array and update each item

```
myList.zipWithIndex foreach { case (item, index) if (condition) => myList.update(index, "updated") }
```

or create a new `ArrayBuffer`

```
myList = (0 until myList.length).map { index => 
  val item = myList(index)
  if (condition) "updated" else item
}
```

Comment: You could use `myList.indices` in your last solution, which returns the same `Range` as your `(0 until myList.length)`.